# How to avoid conditional join in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can we avoid the conditional join in the query below in order to make it faster?

```
SELECT *    
FROM tbl_suite(nolock) SU
INNER JOIN tbl_plan(nolock) PL ON Su.planid = PL.planid
    AND Su.planid = '355' 
INNER JOIN tbl_suiteentry(nolock) SUE ON 
CASE WHEN (SUE.testcaseid != 0) AND SU.suiteid = SUE.suiteid THEN 1
     WHEN SUE.SuiteID = SUE.ChildSuiteID THEN 1 
     ELSE 0
     END = 1
```

Comment: You should probably read this article before you continue littering your queries with nolock. It is not a magic go fast button. It has some very serious baggage that comes with it. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you deadset on continuing that practice you need to specify the WITH keyword. It's omission is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `OR`:

```
select *
from tbl_suite(nolock) SU
inner join tbl_plan(nolock) PL on Su.planid = PL.planid
    and Su.planid = '355'
inner join tbl_suiteentry(nolock) SUE on (
        SUE.testcaseid != 0
        and SU.suiteid = SUE.suiteid
        )
    or (
        SUE.testcaseid = 0
        and SUE.SuiteID = SUE.ChildSuiteID
        )
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
select *
from tbl_suite(nolock) SU
inner join tbl_plan(nolock) PL on Su.planid = PL.planid
    and Su.planid = '355'
inner join tbl_suiteentry(nolock) SUE 
on SUE.SuiteID = case when SUE.testcaseid != 0 then SUE.suiteid else SUE.ChildSuiteID end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes by making them compound condition like below. Also there is no point in using `nolock` hint every where

```
SELECT *    
FROM tbl_suite(nolock) SU
INNER JOIN tbl_plan(nolock) PL ON Su.planid = PL.planid
INNER JOIN tbl_suiteentry(nolock) SUE ON 
(SUE.testcaseid != 0 AND SU.suiteid = SUE.suiteid)
OR (SUE.SuiteID = SUE.ChildSuiteID)
WHERE Su.planid = '355';
```

Answer (score 0):

`or` in `on` clauses makes things really slow.  However, I would guess that you can make this faster an more accurate by fixing the conditions in the `join`:

```
SELECT *    
FROM tbl_suite SU INNER JOIN
     tbl_plan PL
     ON Su.planid = PL.planid AND Su.planid = '355' INNER JOIN
     tbl_suiteentr SUE
     ON (SUE.testcaseid <> 0 AND SU.suiteid = SUE.suiteid) OR
        (SUE.testcaseid <> 0 AND SU.suiteid = SUE.ChildSuiteID)
---------------------------------^ This is a guess
```

I find it hard to believe that you really want the condition to be on two columns in the same table.